# How can i animate my words from bottom to top infinitely in CSS

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to continuously loop two sentences, with a fading effect as they move from bottom to top.

Currently, there's a pause before the animation restarts. I want the sentences to iterate seamlessly within a pink background. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.btn-link_1, .btn-link_2  {
    text-decoration: none; 
  }
  #slideset {
    background-color: #FFD4C2;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%; 
    margin: auto; 
    justify-content: center; 
    display: flex;
    }
  
   .phrases span {
    display:block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    animation: spin_words 10s infinite;
    animation-delay: 0s;
  }
  
  .phrases {
  overflow: hidden; 
  }
  
  
  @keyframes spin_words {
    0%, 10% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  
  15%, 35% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  
  40%, 60% { 
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
  
  65%, 85% {
    transform: translateY(-300%);
  }
  
  90%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(-400%);
  }
 }
```

```html
<div id=slideset>
    <div class="phrases">

      <span style="color: #414042; font-size: 14px; margin: auto;">
        This is the first sentence
      </span>
      <span style="color: #414042; font-size: 14px; margin: auto;"> 
            This is the second sentence
        </span>
     
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: You can start loop from example from place where text is invisible and end it alse where it's invisible - by this you should achieve expected effect

Comment: why don't you use "marquee" for this for reference read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquees.htm

Comment: @kalit any idea why my animation does not loop continuously?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn-link_1,
.btn-link_2 {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#slideset {
  background-color: #FFD4C2;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.phrases span {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  animation: spin_words 5s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.phrases {
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes spin_words {
  0%,
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  33%,
  66% {
    opacity: .5;
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
  66%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=slideset>
  <div class="phrases">
    <span style="color: #414042; font-size: 14px; margin: auto;">
      This is the first sentence
    </span>
    <span style="color: #414042; font-size: 14px; margin: auto;"> 
      This is the second sentence
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```